Wheels spninning very fast but vehicle not moving in Unity3D
I am trying to make a small cannon game in unity. I follow wheelcollider's documentation and setup wheelcollider with radius 3. When I accelerate the wheels are spinning very fast but my cannon is not moving from it place.
I have added basic terrain without any material and I didn't change surface friction.
Rigidbody 
              Mass 1500 

 WheelCollider 
              radius 3
              Spring 35000
              Damper 4500


This probably isn't enough information for anyone to help you. Is the Rigidbody component on your vehicle? Have you tried reducing the mass to something small like 1?

There's many possibilities for this, I've gotten stuck here a few times as well and for me it's always due to how things are set up in the scene and inspector. Here's some things to check out:

The cannon rigidbody bodytype should be set to dynamic.
The friction for either physics material isn't 0.
Gravity is on, try spawning the cannon higher and make sure it falls and contacts the floor.
The wheel colliders are oriented correctly, and aren't horizontal.
All wheel colliders should be children of the cars main rigidbody in the hierarchy.
All wheel colliders are actually touching the ground, something might be blocking it.
Increase force and/or reduce mass, might be too heavy to move


Thanks for reply, your 6th point was important for me I found the wheel colliders was not touching ground properly.
I got that friction for physics material dosen't affect wheelcollider as per docs. I also made adjustments in forward or sideways friction where extremum value should be higher it is important to move forward.
